# Limit problem related to e?

Tags: limits

If I have $\lim_{n \to \infty} of n, given: x_{n+1}= (1+\frac1{x_n})^{x_n}$
What does it mean in relation to the Frist Foias Constant and e?

Comment: Could you please clarify, if $x_n$ is being taken to infinity, why does it appear in the RHS?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, is that an issue?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n,$ where $x_{n+1} = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x_n} \right)^{x_n}$?

Comment: Yes, I’ll fix that

Comment: The limit of $x_n$ is numerically  decently close to $\frac{e}{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is the Foias constant.

Comment: Ok,what does it have to do with the second Foias Constant? Also, what do you mean by “numberically decenltly close”?

Comment: I was just saying that it’s about the ratio of $e$ to the second Foias Number. I take that back, it’s off by about 0.2%.